# 100% cpu usage while iterating through dictionary

Tags: python, optimization

I have python script which synchronizes files from the remote server by comparing with the local files. It uses a file downloading tool written injava. I store filepath, file size and its name in dictionary which looks like:

```
eddsFilesDict = {'/part07_data07/Science/TGO/ACS/SDU_': ['860904
SDU__DACS_51FC_023D8101_2021-155T02-12-17__00001.EXM', '17660866
SDU__DACS_51FB_023D8101_2021-155T02-10-16__00001.EXM', '17660866
SDU__DACS_51FA_023D8101_2021-155T      02-02-18__00001.EXM', '17660866
SDU__DACS_51F9_023D8101_2021-155T02-00-16__00001.EXM']}
```

To list up files on the local machine I use next part of the code:

```
filenames = []
for top, dirs, files in os.walk('/data/local/'):
    for fn in files:
        filenames.append(os.stat(os.path.join(top, fn)).st_size.__str__() + ' ' + os.path.join(fn))
```

But in the following part of my script usage of CPU goes up to 100% and it lasts for 1-2 minutes. I cannot understand why. By experimental way I understood that subprocess is not the thing.

```
for pathname, fileName in eddsFilesDict.items():
    for f in fileName:
        if f not in filenames:
            logger.info('REQUESTING FILE: ' + pathname + '/' + f.split('.')[0].split(' ')[1] + ' FILE SIZE: '
                        + f.split(' ')[0])
            if 'SDU' in f:
                argsFile = shlex.split(
                    '/home/user1/client/bin/fs_client --arc tar') # here I call java tool to start file downloading
                p1 = subprocess.Popen(argsFile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                out, err = p1.communicate()
                logger.warning('REQUESTING FILE: ' + pathname + '/' + f.split('.')[0].split(' ')[1] + ' FILE SIZE: '
                               + f.split(' ')[0] + '\n' + err.__str__())
            elif 'SCI' in f:
                argsFile = shlex.split(
                    '/home/user1/client/bin/fs_client --arc tar')
                p2 = subprocess.Popen(argsFile, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                out, err = p2.communicate()
                logger.warning('REQUESTING FILE: ' + pathname + '/' + f.split('.')[0].split(' ')[1] + ' FILE SIZE: '
                               + f.split(' ')[0] + '\n' + err.__str__())
```

Comment: so what's your concern, that the cpu goes to 100% or that it takes 1-2 minutes to run your program?

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki I'm confused about 100% cpu load

Comment: 100% cpu usage comes when cpu doesnt wait for anything and it has no idle time. So it when processing a dictionary if the cpu is busy processing the dictionary then it uses 100% cpu. If it was a network call the cpu is idle and the usage would reduce.

Comment: The script uses as much CPU power as it can get. If there's nothing interrupting it, it will get 100%.

Comment: Why did you make `filenames` a list? You appear to solely be using it like a set.

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh that sounds good. Thats  good idea I will try it and tell if smth changes.